# Get text from table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with many rows, two of them have the longitude and the latitude, how can I get the numbers with no id or class with jquery? Filtering by words "long" and "lat" and getting the sibling text? thanks

```
<Table>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>latitude</td>
     <td>038383</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>longitude</td>
     <td> -304828</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("td:contains('latitude')").siblings()` gives you the list of  elements that contain latitudes. Use the `.text()` method to get the value of each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each` method for td and use `$(item).next('td')` to get value of latitude

```js
let latitude;
let longitude;
$('td').each(function(index,item){
  if($(item).text() == 'latitude'){
     latitude = $(item).next('td').text();
  }
  if($(item).text() == 'longitude'){
     longitude = $(item).next('td').text();
  }
});
console.log("latitude:" + latitude);
console.log("longitude:" + longitude);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>latitude</td>
     <td>038383</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>longitude</td>
     <td> -304828</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did an example on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7fcrdkge/1/ this was wrapped into an each closure, this should print every lat/lon of the table

Code:

```
var el = $("table").find("tr");
el.each(function(i, e) {
  var lat = $(e).find("td:contains('latitude')").next().text();
  var lon = $(e).find("td:contains('longitude')").next().text();
  console.log("lat: " + lat);
  console.log("lon: " + lon);
});
```